# Limiting Emacs incremental search to a function definition

Tags: isearch

Any existing package that can do incremental search inside a function definition instead of the whole buffer?

Now the best I can do is to turn on `semantic-mode` along with `semantic-stickyfunc-mode` and carefully search within its scope.

Comment: Can you explain what you want more clearly?  Do what to do the search from an elisp function, or do want to search interactively within the text of a function definition in some file?  In the latter case, you could use narrowing to limit the search.

Comment: `C-x n d` (or `M-x narrow-to-defun`) then search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @xuchunyang said in a comment to your question, you can first narrow the buffer to the function definition.

Or you can use library [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus), which lets you [search just the active region](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus#isearchp-restrict-to-region-flag), without narrowing.

Non-`nil` option `isearchp-restrict-to-region-flag` does this. You can use `C-x n` (command `isearchp-toggle-region-restriction`) during search to toggle this option value.

Also, deactivation of the active region when you search is controlled by option `isearchp-deactivate-region-flag`.

(NOTE: For search to be limited to the active region in *Info*, you
must also use library [Info+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InfoPlus).)